# cake : how to update a specific field in HABT relation?

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp

I have **$hasAndBelongsToMany** relation between projects and documents and they are linked with associative table **projects_documents**(id, project_id,document_id). Something likes that

```
class Projects extends AppModel {
    var $name = 'Projects';
    var $hasAndBelongsToMany = array(
        'Documents' => array(
            'className' => 'Documents',
            'joinTable' => 'projects_documents',
            'foreignKey' => 'project_id',
            'associationForeignKey' => 'document_id',
        ),
    );
```

It is working perfectly when updates and inserts are required. I’m required to add a flag field of each document of project. So I added a field in projects_documents, now table structure is id, project_id,document_id and flag. I know associated table updates by cake native function, that’s why it updates project_id and document_id by itself.

My question is how I can update the newly added field flag for each write operation. I’ve tried with manual queries but I want to implement this according to cake standards.

Thanks

Comment: @MoyedAnsari remember that Model names are always singulars: *Project*, *Document*.
Take a look to CakePHP Conventions:
http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/getting-started/cakephp-conventions.html

Comment: Thanks for highlighting @manzapanza